# Форматированный вывод

Tags: c#

В программе:

```
Decimal a = 7m;
Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", a);
```

Вывод: 7,00 ?

Без знака валюты и с вопросительным знаком в конце. Что надо сделать?

Comment: а у меня в данном виде пример вообще не компилируется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, в коде ошибка, правильно будет вывод делать вот так:

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0:C}", a);
```

Не там стояли фигурные скобки.

А во-вторых, в остальном - всё верно, так и должно быть.
А именно:
Вы указываете переменную денежного типа `decimal a = 7m`, которая должна вывестись с знаком валюты. Какой именно знак валюты будет использован - берется из региональных настроек системы. В случае с российскими региональными настройками, это будет рубль, и знак валюты, который должен вывестись - ₽.

Но у вас идет тут вывод в консоль, которая, в свою очередь, использует для отображения шрифт, в котором нет этого символа, потому и выводится знак вопроса вместо него.

**UPD:** 
У меня под Win 7 следующий код выводит всё корректно:

```
        decimal a = 7m;
        var s = string.Format("{0:C}", a);
        MessageBox.Show(s);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _всё верно, так и должно быть._ - _Без знака валюты и с вопросительным знаком в конце_?

Comment: Обновил ответ. В данном контексте вопрос и есть знак валюты.

Comment: @BlackWitcher, Спасибо за ответ. В реальном коде кавычки стоят правильно. Это я ЗДЕСЬ ошибся по неопытности

Comment: Изменил настройки на доллар, и всё получилось. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, что мой ответ оказался полезным.